# problems transposing columns using cut

Tags: bash, sh, transpose, cut

I want to transpose a 3-column text file to three separate files with one line each.
In other words, take this file:

in_file

```
1   22  0.8
4   21  0.73
3   30  1.56
5   12  0.92
```

and produce the following 3 files:

out_file1

```
1   4   3   5
```

out_file2

```
22  21  30  12
```

out_file3

```
0.8 0.73    1.56    0.92
```

I tried to use cut to do this:

```
cut -d' ' -f1 in_file | tr -s '\n' '\t' >> out_file1
cut -d' ' -f2 in_file | tr -s '\n' '\t' >> out_file2
cut -d' ' -f3 in_file | tr -s '\n' '\t' >> out_file3
```

however, what I get is this:

out_file1

```
1   4   3   5
```

out_file2

```
22  21  30  12
```

out_file3

```
0.8
    0.73
    1.56
    0.92
```

I can't figure out why it works for the first 2 columns and not the third.

Grateful for any help!

Comment: Are you sure about the delimiter is always one single blank space?

Comment: The delimiter is always a tab.
Actually, I realized there was a mistake in my post above - I've now updated how the out_file3 actually looks like (a new tab at the beginning of each line).

Comment: The input delimiter - is it a tab or a space?
When it's a single space, your code works for me (centos 6.5)
You could add 'cat in_file | tr -s " " ' before the cut

Comment: I don't understand why you are getting an almost correct output. If delimiter is always a tab the `cut -d' ' -f3 in_file` command should be wrong, since it is using a space as delimiter instead of tab.

Comment: No, I've double-checked, and I am using a single horisontal tab as a delimiter, not a space - which should explain why it successfully identifies the fields (and correctly transposes the first 2 columns). What I'm trying to figure out is why, for column 3, it doesn't remove the new line like it does for the first 2 columns (it adds a horisontal tab).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is most likely the delimiter which you've typed as a literal tab instead of `\t`, here's a loop that does all three files:

```
for i in {1..3}; do
    cut -d$'\t' "-f${i}" in_file | column >> "outfile_${i}.txt"
done
```

Here we loop over a sequense of `{1..3}`, set the delimiter to tab with the special syntax: `-d$'\t'`, pipe the data to `column` which automatically lines up the values and append that to the correct file.

Comment: thanks for the input. I tried specifying -d$'\t' instead of a literal tab, but it produces the same result.

However, I figured out that the problem was the \n. The text files I'm reading are produced by a script written in PHP, in which the newline is \r\n, as opposed to \n in unix.

Comment: Tab is the default delimiter, so you should be able to just skip the `-d` option.

Answer (score 0):

A bit faster if awk is availble

```
awk '{ for( i=1; i<=NF; i++) printf( "%s ", $i) > ("file" i)}' YourFile
```

note:
 - `>` and not `>>` because awk evaluate the redirection only at file opening (so creation and not add in this case)

for your cut problem, is separator always 1 space char between column